Dynamic Sequence in Pentaho
I'm trying to add a sequence in my flow based on the last (max) value in SalesNo column which is a sequence.
I'm using oracle cloud, conecting through Wallet.
For example, Sales table has 100 rows, the next SalesNo should be 101.
First, I tried adding the sequence checking Use DB to get sequence option but it seems like sequences button disabled, I type the name but then it shows this message:
Add sequence.0 - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Because of an error, this step can't continue:
Add sequence.0 - Error reading next value of sequence [SSSALESNOSEQ] from database
DB SEQUENCE ATTEMPT
Then I tried to use variables to pass the value but although I setted the variable as integer, it seems like pass the value as string. It shows this error:
Add sequence.0 - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Counter value for start could not be parsed, original value is [%%VALOR%%] which becomes [193.0].Error: For input string: "193.0".
Add sequence.0 - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Add sequence]
SStoreTest - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : Step [Add sequence.0] failed to initialize!
VARIABLE SETTINGS
Thanks in advance.

Maybe weird question, but for what purpose do you want to use this? Normally when inserting you insert without sequence, since the database appoints it, and second if you want to know the sequence of new inserts, there is an option in output table to return the sequence value of the record with the record after input. This coversd most cases. So trying to imagine the reason (and thus the best potential sollution). PS> the first way does work for me... keep in mind that databases are case sensitive, and might need schema names, dependent on database type)
